# Selecting Every Second Level In CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How would you select every second **level** in the stack of **infinite** levels using CSS only?

Sample code:

```
<div>
    1
    <div>
        2
        <div>
            3
            <div>
                4
                <div>
                    5
                    <div>
                        [...]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Visual **example** of the preferred result:

[image]

**Note:** no JavaScript assistance needed; there is no problem when the number of levels is known.

Comment: Is there a way to add a class to every second div as it is created?

Comment: Adding a class to every second level would obviously solve the problem, however this would require and intervention from outside (i.e. JavaScript) which is not what I was looking for as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is no problem when the number of levels is known, when it is *not* known then it becomes impossible with CSS only, not even if you are able to anchor the topmost `div` to some other element with a selector.

Comment: I tried using direct-child selector '>', naively and with no success. You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about a different tag, like span for the second level and target that in CSS div span.

What's creating this infinite iteration ?

Comment: Great point. I do not know why I used divs instead of unordered lists, because actually I was working on a x-level drop-down navigation and wanted to use different background color on every second level, i.e.: <ul><li>1<ul><li>2</li></ul></li></ul>. Any further thoughts?